# PHP Parsing Large CSV File For Specific Info

Tags: php, csv

I am currently working on a project for a folding@home community to help with competitions and community stats tracking. The issue that I am running into, is how large the Stanford flat file is. Currently it is at 1.7 million lines and growing.

My issue currently, is that I am not able to get the proper info about the users that I want based on their team. The code seems to work but it doesn't write the data to the csv file.

CSV Library: [LINK](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php)

Code:

```
require_once 'parsecsv.lib.php';
$csv = new parseCSV();
$csv->delimiter = "\t";
$csv->parse('daily_user_summary.txt');
$out = fopen('new.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($out, array('name', 'newcredit', 'team'));
foreach($csv->data as $item) {
  if(array_key_exists('team', $item)) {
    if($item['team'] == "37726") {
      fputcsv($out, $item);
    }
  }
}
fclose($out);
```

Before I would get an issue where the code would run indefinitely but it seems to be fixed with using array_key_exists.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? Are there any errors?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Before using array_key_exists I would get `[Thu Mar 23 17:34:02.644925 2017] [:error] [pid 2464] [client 10.0.1.133:7544] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: team in /var/www/html/parse.php on line 17`

And it would just keep going until I restarted apache

Comment: First of all its bad idea to parse a file with millions of lines. That's why databases were developed. If you are on linux you can use "grep -w 'daily_user_summary.txt' -e '37726' " command to retrieve the lines with matching words. In the for-loop can you place this, print_r($item); die(); , So that the for loop prints one row and exit. I would like to see what's being retrieved.

Comment: @blokeish It runs without error but it does not display anything. Even if I run it via CLI.

Comment: If I slim the file down a bit, I do get this print `Array ( [name] => Klue22 [newcredit] => 2043580213 [sum(total)] => 105974 [team] => 37726 )`

Comment: When you run the script with original csv file does the script finish execution, say with CLI. I suspect that the $csv->parse is not able to handle the large file or is taking too long. Put a echo statement before and after '$csv->parse...' to see if its stuck there.

Comment: @blokeish Surprisingly it is working [Image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/53g8sv8jixvf97u/chrome_2017-03-23_23-37-00.png)